# Mostrar Imagen o Mensaje Cargando Boostrap Vista MVC(Sin ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una aplicación asp.net MVC 5, y tengo un proceso en una vista que se tarda como 5 minutos al hacer submit, entonces quiero bloquear la vista y mostrar un modal o una imagen de cargando o de espere por favor(mientras proceso los datos de mi controlador), para que el usuario no se desespere, no quiero utilizar ajax, quiero saber si hay alguna alternativa  para hacerlo con javascript .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

Dale un id a tu boton de submit
Dale un id a tu form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("miAction", "miController", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "miForma" }))
```

Click

```
$("#btnGuardar").click(function (ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();

//Mandar llamar modal, bloquear pantalla o lo que se necesite

 $('#miForma').submit();//Llamamos el submit de la forma

}
```